# CJK Languages Pronunciation APIs

Tags: nlp

Are there any good (preferably open) APIs or databases of pronunciation audio files for Chinese/Japanese/Korean languages? I’ve been looking around, but somehow couldn’t find anything other than [Forvo](http://api.forvo.com/) or Google Translate. Both are an overkill for me, since I only need data for those languages, and only pronunciations, no translations.

Comment: When you ask for a pronunciation in Forvo API you will get a URL to an audio file containing the pronunciation.

Comment: I know. Forvo is really good, but it’s quite pricey for me, since I only intend to use a very limited subset of its pronunciations data (only for those three languages).

Answer (score 1):

How many words are you looking for? Downloading up to 1000 files per day is free with the Forvo API. And if you need all that many more, it would be fair to pay them.

If a transcription is good enough for you, there are good open-source dictionaries for Chinese, and Korean can be converted syllable-by-syllable because Korean uses an alphabet. Japanese is the only difficulty, since Japanese characters are often pronounced differently according to the context.

Comment: With Forvo the issue isn’t the quantity, it’s rather the permission of commercial use, which isn’t available even for “Premium” 5,000 requests pack.